# magento2: how validation work in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery, form-validation

In magento1 we can check validation like this:

```
var formToValidate = $('form-validate');
    var validator = new Validation(formToValidate);
    if(validator.validate()) {
        // Here we can code after validation.
    }
```

but in magento2 i want to check all validation but don't want to submit form after success. so how can I perform with magento2 form?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-button-name').click(function () { // The button type should be "button" and not submit
            if ($('#form-name').valid()) {
                alert("Validation pass");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: works like charm.!!

Answer (score 4):

**You can use solution where you have data-mage-init validation**

```
  require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui'
    ], function($){
        $(".MYbuttonClass").on("click", function() {
            
           if ( $('.form-Class').validation() && $('.form-Class').validation('isValid') === true) {
                //Submit form    
                $('.form-Class').submit();
  
            }

        });

    });
```