# How to submit a form to controller using ajax with magento 2 validation

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax, form-validation

My form is like this

```
<form  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' id="donation-request-form" method="post" data-hasrequired="* Required Fields">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 row-padding">
                <span class="fname-icon"></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control fname" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" data-validate='{"required":true}'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 row-padding">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button button-section">
        <input class="btn-orange" type="submit" value="Request Donation" onclick="SendForm()">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my **SendForm()** function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SendForm() {       
    var customurl = "<?php echo $baseURL_l.'emails/index/index'?>";
    alert(customurl);
    jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : customurl,
    data : jQuery('#donation-request-form').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
    });
}
```

If i click submit button without filling any values of the form it will redirect to the controller and after the form validation is happening.

I want to validate first and submit the form to controller second.
I do not want to do any custom js validation.I want to use only magento validation.

Comment: check answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93869/magento2-how-validation-work-in-magento2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (jQuery('#donation-request-form').valid()) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : customurl,
    data : jQuery('#donation-request-form').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a good way of form submission with AJAX while using magento2 default form validation which I would like to share with the community.

We simply use below code for form validation

```
require([‘jquery’,’mage/validation’], function($){

    var dataForm = $(‘#form-validate’);

    dataForm.mage(‘validation’, {});

});
```

We can extend this to :

```
require([‘jquery’,’mage/validation’], function($) {

  var dataForm = $(‘#form-validate’);

  dataForm.mage(‘validation’, {});

  $(‘button#submit-button’).click( function() { //can be replaced with any event   

    var status = dataForm.validation(‘isValid’); //validates form and returns boolean

    if(status) {
      console.log(‘form is validated’); //form is valid
      //Do the AJAX call here

    } else {

      console.log(‘form is not validated’); 

    }   

  });

});
```

You can find detail description [in this link](http://www.navinbista.com/ajax-form-submit-magento2-default-form-validation/).

Hope this helps!!